# how to solve docker-sync command not found on Mac Catalina

Tags: docker

I tried to follow official instructions to install `docker-sync` as follow

```
sudo gem install docker-sync

Successfully installed docker-sync-0.5.14
Parsing documentation for docker-sync-0.5.14
Done installing documentation for docker-sync after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

But when try to run

```
docker-sync --version
zsh: command not found: docker-sync
```

I'm out of clues how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run this

```
gem install docker-sync --user-install -n /usr/local/bin
```

post that you should be able to start docker-sync